# Differential equation $f''(x)+2 x f(x)f'(x) = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

I am trying to solve,

$ f''(x)+2 x f(x)f'(x) = 0$

with boundary conditions $f(-\infty)=1$ and $f(\infty)=0$. I have found that for instance $f(x) = 3/2 x^{-2}$ but obviously it does not satisfy the proper boundary conditions. Any ideas for a solution?

Comment: One can see that a constant function is a general solution. Thus a possible solution with the given boundary conditions could be a step function that goes from 1 to 0 and steps somewhere at $x_0$, i.e. $f(x)=H(-(x-x_0))$, where $H$ is the Heaviside function. But $f(x)$ could be any piecewise constant function. The derivatives would be problematic at the step points, but otherwise it'd be fine.

It is not clear whether a smooth solution with the given boundary conditions exists.

Answer (score 3):

(this is not an answer, but, this doesn't do well as a comment)

To solve $y''+2xyy'=0$ we might notice $(xy^2)' = y^2+ 2xyy'$ thus
$$ y''+(xy^2)'-y^2 = 0 $$
or
$$ (y'+xy^2)' - y^2 = 0 $$
I also tried multiplying by $y'$ to look for some energy equation, but, the presence of that $x$ is cramping my style. I bet someone can solve this.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

This belongs to a generalized Emden–Fowler equation.

$f''(x)+2xf(x)f'(x)=0$

$\dfrac{d^2f}{dx^2}=-2xf\dfrac{df}{dx}$

$\therefore\dfrac{d^2x}{df^2}=2fx\left(\dfrac{dx}{df}\right)^2$

Follow the method in http://science.fire.ustc.edu.cn/download/download1/book%5Cmathematics%5CHandbook%20of%20Exact%20Solutions%20for%20Ordinary%20Differential%20EquationsSecond%20Edition%5Cc2972_fm.pdf#page=377:

Let $\begin{cases}y=\dfrac{df}{dx}\\t=f^2\end{cases}$ ,

Then $\dfrac{d^2t}{dy^2}=2y^{-1}t^{-\frac{1}{2}}\left(\dfrac{dt}{dy}\right)^3$

$\therefore\dfrac{d^2y}{dt^2}=-2t^{-\frac{1}{2}}y^{-1}$

Which reduces to an Emden–Fowler equation.

Comment: this I did not teach in my DEqns course. Cool.